# KendoUI grid display total number of records

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I am using the kendoUI grid to show records from a table. I would like to display the total number of records so the table. something like

**showing 1-20 of 1203 records**

is there a way to show the total number of records using KendoUI grid?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All you have to do is add this to your .kendoGrid

```
    dataBound: function (e) {
            //total bits needs to be removed because dataBound fires every time the gird pager is pressed.
            $('#totalBits').remove();
            //add the total count to the pager div.  or whatever div you want... just remember to clear it before you add it.
            $('.k-grid-pager').append('<div id="totalBits">' + this.dataSource.total() + '</div>')
     }
```

Comment: Which you can add if you are using the `MVC` wrapper, say in a Razor view by adding the `.Events(ev => ev.DataBound("updateTotals"))` call to the `Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Cases)` call.

Answer (score 2):

The MVC wrapper code I used to display a footer(pager) with only the record count looked like this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(dataSource)
    .Columns(...)
    .Pageable(p => p.Numeric(false)
                    .PreviousNext(false)
                    .Messages(m => m.Display("Matching Students: {2}")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the option pageable.messages.display, you can review the documentation:  [Here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-pageable.messages)